# Different database for some models in lithium

Tags: php, lithium

My app requires me to use 2 databases. Most models use data from only one model but some models require me to use a different database.
Is it possible to specify in a model which database to use? I am using MongoDB for my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Lithium docs](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/working-with-data/using-models.wiki) explain multiple connections, in the section "Model Creation and Configuration"

From that page, if you want to use the "backup" connection:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
class Posts extends \lithium\data\Model {
    protected $_meta = array(
        'connection' => 'backup'
    );
}
?>
```

Further explanation from the same page:

> Once your model's $_meta property has been configured, Lithium merges it with the default settings at runtime. Because the Post model has a specified connection, the backup connection is used instead of the default.